# Java tesseract return co-ordinates of text location

Tags: java, eclipse, tesseract, tess4j

I am using Java in eclipse and want to return the co-ordinates of all recognized text which is found. My code which I attained through tess4j currently outputs all of the text found, this code is below:

```
import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ColorConvertOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;



public class TesseractExample {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        try 
        {           
               String x = System.getProperty("user.dir");
                File b = new File(x+"/inDCM");
            File imageFile = new File(b+"/surrey.png");
            BufferedImage img =  ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance(); 
            ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);  
            ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(cs, null);
            op.filter(img, img); 
            try 
            {   
                String result = instance.doOCR(img);
               
                System.out.println("The result is: " + result);
                
            }
            catch (TesseractException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("error:" + e);
            }
        }finally{
            
        }
    }}
```

Is it possible to retrieve the co-ordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the coordinates through `ResultIterator` object available in the low-level `TessBaseAPI` API. Code examples can be found in unit tests in the project's [repo](https://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/code/HEAD/tree/Tess4J_3/trunk/test/net/sourceforge/tess4j/).

Comment: Thank you for the response, the repository provided was great. After trying to implement the TestGetSegmentedRegions() from the TesseractTest.java. I get the following error on the line.

`instance.getSegmentedRegions(bi, level);`

The instance I am using does not recognise the method getSegmentedRegions(). Have I not configured something correctly?

Comment: Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I believe so, I downloaded it straight from the website:

terminal states: tesseract 3.03
leptonica-1.70

Comment: I believe you have an old version. Try version [3.2.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tess4j/files/tess4j/) or from [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j/3.2.1).

Comment: I have just downloaded the new version and updated the libraries, unfortunately this issue is still there with the getSegmentedRegions() function... I have also made sure that all of the imports are the same as the ones in the repo you have provided. all of them work apart from `net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITesseract.RenderedFormat;` - could that be the cause?

Comment: I can only guess that an old JAR still lingers in your classpath. A complete cleanup or reinstall of Tess4J may help. Put it in a separate folder and run the unit tests: `ant test` or `mvn test`

Comment: You're a legend, thank you for the help. I forgot to remove the old tess4j.jar after adding the new one, and reloaded my workspace. works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Tess4j will be really helpful here for you. [This is an example I found on the test cases](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/blob/master/src/test/java/net/sourceforge/tess4j/TesseractTest.java#L261)

```
/**
 * Test of getSegmentedRegions method, of class Tesseract.
 *
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@Test
public void testGetSegmentedRegions() throws Exception {
    logger.info("getSegmentedRegions at given TessPageIteratorLevel");
    File imageFile = new File(testResourcesDataPath, "eurotext.png");
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    int level = TessPageIteratorLevel.RIL_SYMBOL;
    logger.info("PageIteratorLevel: " + Utils.getConstantName(level, TessPageIteratorLevel.class));
    List<Rectangle> result = instance.getSegmentedRegions(bi, level);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        Rectangle rect = result.get(i);
        logger.info(String.format("Box[%d]: x=%d, y=%d, w=%d, h=%d", i, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height));
    }

    assertTrue(result.size() > 0);
}
```

The TessPageIteratorLevel will define how to segmentate the content of the image.(i.e.: character or word)

[TessPageIteratorLevel Options](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/tess4j/ITessAPI.java#L138)

```
    /**
     * Block of text/image/separator line.
     */
    public static final int RIL_BLOCK = 0;
    /**
     * Paragraph within a block.
     */
    public static final int RIL_PARA = 1;
    /**
     * Line within a paragraph.
     */
    public static final int RIL_TEXTLINE = 2;
    /**
     * Word within a textline.
     */
    public static final int RIL_WORD = 3;
    /**
     * Symbol/character within a word.
     */
    public static final int RIL_SYMBOL = 4;
```